# Set Color codes to the legends in vba

Tags: vba, excel, charts, pivot-table

I have pivot tables in each worksheets and I have to compare them but the colors for the legends in each of the worksheet is different.
How to I set the colors?

For example, If my legend entry is "ISO" I want it to be always "blue", if its "LAT" I want it to be "Red" in every sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by manipulating the `Series` objects in the `SeriesCollection` property of a `Chart`.

I've written a short example method below that takes a worksheet, a legend name and a target RGB color. It loops the sheet's shapes, and if they contain charts, looks for a `Series` with the specified `legendName`. If it fits, it changes the forecolor to the specified RGB color.

```
Private Sub FormatShapeLegend(sheet As Worksheet, legendName As String, targetColor As MsoRGBType)
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim chrt As Chart
    Dim s As Series

    For Each shp In sheet.Shapes
        If shp.HasChart Then
            Set chrt = shp.Chart

            'Loop the dataseries to find the legend with the desired name.
            For Each s In chrt.SeriesCollection
                'If the name fits, go ahead and format the series.
                If LCase(s.Name) = LCase(legendName) Then
                    s.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = targetColor
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Example usage:

```
FormatShapeLegend ActiveSheet, "ISO", RGB(0, 0, 255)
```