# VBA to update chart based on headers containing some text

Tags: vba, excel, excel-charts

I have a chart that helps me plot out a sequence of events by person. I need some classes of events to have consistency when I chart.

For example, Jane gets hired twice in her career. I want that class of hire to be the same. However, Excel will interrupt these as different classes because one is named 01-Hire and the other 02-Hire. All hires should be blue in the example below.

I want some code to search for "Hire" in the header and then then apply a consistent color. **Note**, there may be different headers among sequences, so the code needs to be smart enough to only group things that contain the same text (not the sequence number).

The closest thing I could find to doing this was here:
[Set Color codes to the legends in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34153465/set-color-codes-to-the-legends-in-vba)

```
Private Sub FormatShapeLegend(sheet As Worksheet, legendName As String, targetColor As MsoRGBType)
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim chrt As Chart
    Dim s As Series

    For Each shp In sheet.Shapes
        If shp.HasChart Then
            Set chrt = shp.Chart

            'Loop the dataseries to find the legend with the desired name.
            For Each s In chrt.SeriesCollection
                'If the name fits, go ahead and format the series.
                If LCase(s.Name) = LCase(legendName) Then
                    s.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = targetColor
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub

FormatShapeLegend ActiveSheet, "ISO", RGB(0, 0, 255)
```

I want to do this for all classes below similar to the chart.

**Desired output**
[image]

**The data table**
[image]

**The raw code**
    Row Labels  01 - Hire   01 - Promotion  01 - Term   02 - Hire   02 - Promotion  02 - Term   03 - Hire   03 - Promotion  03 - Term
    Jane    38      10              29
    Ben             15  50              10
    Joe 68  56              10      7
    Lisa            61                  41
    Jenny   24
    Jerry   81  16

Comment: "I want some code" questions typically don't last long here...

Comment: See the table. I also added in the code from the table, but this forum doesn't lend itself well to table pastes. Not sure what else I can do to make the data pull quicker.

Comment: I mean questions which ask for VBA but don't *include* any VBA, or any description of what you might have tried and what problems you had...

Comment: Ah, got it. I'm not very good with VBA, so I don't have a great starting point aside from the code I listed... If there is a non-VBA solution, then I'm game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your series labels are always repeating "Hire x","Prom x","Term x" then something like this would work:

```
Dim s As Series, x As Long
x = 0

For Each s In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection
    x = x + 1
    s.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Array(vbBlue, vbRed, vbGreen)(x Mod 3)
Next s
```

If you need to do it based off the series name then:

```
Dim s As Series, clr As Long, nm As String

For Each s In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection

    nm = LCase(s.Name)

    clr = vbYellow 'default
    If nm Like "*hire*" Then
        clr = vbBlue
    ElseIf nm Like "*prom*" Then
        clr = vbGreen
    ElseIf nm Like "*term*" Then
        clr = vbRed
    End If

    s.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = clr

Next s
```

Comment: Brilliant, but the sequence could differ, e.g. 01 Hire, 01 Term, 02 Hire, 02 Promotion, 03 Term, 04 Transfer, 04 Hire, etc.. I updated the request.